# Behave of the solution as $t\to\infty$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following ODE $$y'+7y=t+e^{-2t}$$ It is easy that $y=\frac{7t-1}{49}+\frac{1}{5e^{2t}}+\frac{c}{e^{7t}}$, where $c$ is a constant. I want to determine how solution behaves as $t\to\infty.$ I thought I just need to take the limit and this showed that $y\to\infty.$ Since the answer in the book is $y=\frac{7t-1}{49}$ as $t\to\infty.$ Should I graph the solution to get this answer, I meant should I graph the direction field to answer this question? Any advice?

Comment: You do not need a graph, just notice that $\frac{1}{5e^{2t}}+\frac{c}{e^{7t}}\to0$ when $t\to\infty$.

Comment: Something like what?

Comment: @Conifold, what is the general way to check the behave of the solution.

Comment: Remove all terms that go to $0$ at $\infty$.

Comment: @Conifold, conisder the solution $y=3\frac{4t \sin t+\cos t}{16t}+\frac{c}{t}$ . So, as $t\to \infty$ $y=\frac{3}{4}\sin t.$ Right? I just want to make I got the idea right.

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: @Conifold, I did not notice that before. That is helpful.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, let's throw some unnecessary high-powered machinery at this problem and use a method inspired by (or perhaps even equal to) the method of dominant balance.

Looking at the right-hand side of the equation, we can see that at $t\to\infty$, the $t$ term dominates. For this reason, let's suppose that
$$
7y(t) \sim t\Longrightarrow y\sim\frac{t}{7}.
$$
Plugging in $y=t/7$ to both sides yields
$$
\frac{1}{7}+7\frac{t}{7}\sim t+e^{-2t}.
$$
It is certainly true that the
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{\mbox{left-hand side}}{\mbox{right-hand side}}=1,
$$
so it seems like this was a good choice to make.

Next, we suppose that
$$
y=\frac{t}{7}+\epsilon(t),
$$
where $\epsilon(t)\ll t$, which is to say,
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{\epsilon(t)}{t}=0.
$$
Plugging this into the differential equation yields
$$
49\epsilon+7\epsilon'=-1+7e^{-2t}.
$$
On the right-hand side, the dominant term is the $-1$, so let's suppose that
$$
\epsilon\sim -1/49.
$$
Pugging this in, we get
$$
-1+0\sim-1+7e^{-2t},
$$
and the sides still clearly balance.

Thus, we arrive at an asymptotic solution of the form
$$
y(t) \sim \frac{t}{7}-\frac{1}{49}.
$$
We could stop there, because the rest of the terms are likely to be exponentially small, but let's see how much of this expansion we can get!

---

So, we proceed again by guessing that
$$
\epsilon(t) = -\frac{1}{49}+\epsilon_2(t),
$$
where again, $\epsilon(t)\ll\epsilon_2(t)$ as $t\to\infty$.  Plugging this into the differential equation for $\epsilon$, we get
$$
7\epsilon_2+\epsilon_2'=e^{-2t}.
$$
Now there is only one term on the right, so we guess that
$$
\epsilon_2\sim ae^{-2t}
$$
Plugging this in, we get
$$
5ae^{-2t}\sim e^{-2t},
$$
which again balances!  If, in the next step, we actually want these terms to *cancel*, then we should choose $a=1/5$.

So, guess the next iteration to be
$$
\epsilon_2(t) = \frac{1}{5}e^{-2t} +\epsilon_3(t),
$$
again where $\epsilon_2\ll\epsilon_3$.  Plugging this in, we arrive at
$$
\epsilon_3'=-7\epsilon_3.
$$
We've finally gotten to the point where we know the solution, i.e.,
$$
\epsilon_3(t) = ce^{-7t}.
$$

Putting everything back together, we arrive at the asymptotic expansion
$$
y(t) \sim \frac{t}{7}-\frac{1}{49}+\frac{1}{5}e^{-2t}+ce^{-7t}.
$$
Of course, it turns out that this is the *exact* solution, but what's the fun in figuring out exact solutions when you can perform an asymptotic analysis!